# jsf with eclipse: Library of referenced project not found

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat7

I have started a JSF project with Eclipse Indigo and Apache Tomcat 7 which references an other java project which depends on joda time. When I run the jsf project I get a NoClassDefFoundError for org/joda/time/DateTime. I tried to deploy the library with the java as well as with the jsf project with no success. Adding it as deployment assembly or to to Tomcat's lib folder didn't help.

Can anyone help me get this to work?

Cheers,
AC

Comment: why dont you add the needed jar to the lib folder which inside the WEB-INF of the JSF project?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to fix the problem with multiple projects so I merged all projects into one and now it works.

If someone knows a solution for the original problem I'd still be interrested to hear about it.